# platform_browser_dynamic_1.bootstrap is not a function + angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

Everything was working fine & suddenly not sure why I am getting this error:

`TypeError: platform_browser_dynamic_1.bootstrap is not a function`

Below is my component:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ContactService } from '../../services/contactService';
// Initialize jquery
declare var $:JQueryStatic;

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    pipes: [],
    providers: [ContactService],
    directives: [],
    styles: [String(require('../../../../../static/v4/angular/scss/login.scss')),],
    templateUrl: '../../../../../templates/v4/angular/login/login.html'
})
export class Login {
    @ViewChild('spreadsheetTable') el:ElementRef;
    public statctUrl = STATIC_URL;
    constructor(private contactService: ContactService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

Edit: here is my bootstrapping file main.ts (from RC4 -> RC5):

```
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
import {bootstrap, platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';

import {APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from './app/app.routes';
import {AppModule} from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
])
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic` from the RC5 version of Angular2.

- Install modules using NPM

  ```
  npm install @angular/{core,common,compiler,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic} --save
  ```
- Import and use the module

  ```
  import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
  import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
  ```

Comment: but what's problem with this `bootstrap(App, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
])` since till now it was working fine, just now its creating this problem

Comment: It's deprecated with RC5. See this doc: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html.

Comment: Ok but now I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function` for `styles: [String(require('../../../static/v4/angular/scss/app.scss'))],`

Comment: Also started getting this error: `platform_browser_dynamic_1.platformBrowserDynamic is not a function`. added my main.ts

Answer (score 0):

> platform_browser_dynamic_1.platformBrowserDynamic is not a function.

This just means that Angular2 doesn't recognize this function. As Thierry said, you need to upgrade properly to Angular2 **RC5**.
This means you need to updates all the needed packages in your package.json file.

My **package.json** file with the last versions is looking like that :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",

    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",

    "systemjs": "0.19.36",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
```

You can do as Thierry said, and manually update all the packages, or you can use a tool for that as well. I recommend using **npm-check-updates** : https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates.

Typing **ncu** shows me what packages need to be updated, and **ncu -u** will get the latests versions for each package.

After that, if you did it correctly, and if you did configure the new Angular2 RC5 NgModules correctly, your app should work just like before.

Hope this helps.